# Can we create or update user and group in IBM clearQuset through CM API?

Tags: clearquest

I am working with clearQuest 7.1.2.
I have two question in clearQuest 7.1.2 ..

1. I need to update user and group through CM API provided by IBM. But I could not find any such API for user and group in same. how do I do that ?
2. Is there 64 bit clearQuest installation available ?
   Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- There are no specific API for update Group and User in ClearQuest, CMAPI only provide setter method for both object's attributes. If we use those provided setter method to modify the attribute it will overwrite its value, if you don't want to overwrite you have to write code in that way.

2- No there is no 64 bit ClearQuest installation available .
see this link - 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21330262